# Airplay and disconnection: the music cuts frequently

Tags: wireless-networking, speakers, airplay

I use my mac (on maverick) with an airplay speaker and I have a some disconnection problems.

Frequently, the music is cut and doesn't restart automatically. It's impossible to use speaker with it.
So I do some tests and I found some trails but I don't know how to resolve this.

If I play a mp3 320kb/s, it cut more often than a 128kb/s (it happens with 128kb/s notwithstanding).

So, the size of the music seems to play in my problem.

I run a tcpdump to see what happens when the music cut.

Here is when the music plays:
10.0.0.1 is my host. 10.0.0.3 is the speaker.

```
18:34:22.197963 IP 10.0.0.11.54966 > 10.0.0.3.opennl: UDP, length 1018
```

And when the music cuts:

```
18:34:54.294150 IP 10.0.0.11 > 10.0.0.3: ICMP 10.0.0.11 udp port 6002 unreachable, length 36
```

So, it seems the speaker is unreachable.

My question is why ? I don't understand why the speaker becomes unreachable sometime, never on the same times.

Comment: Are you doing this on wireless? UDP will have dropped packets regardless, and at 320kb/s, maybe this has something to do with it? What happens when your try playing a movie instead of music?

Comment: Yes airplay is a wireless protocol. When I play a video on my TV with DLNA protocol (wireless too), I have the same problem.

Comment: I'm not a big fan of wireless. Too many factors that can interrupt your signal. What's your access point? Channels are set properly? It's maybe worth testing another access point.

Comment: I become not fan too with these problems but I can't have many cables in the floor ;). My channel is unique in the building (I checked that) What do you mean by "testing another access point", I have only one router in my home and the airplay protocol is point to point connection